# duplicate key value violates unique constraint - but no such values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, unique-constraint

Ran:

```
truncate table tableA restart identity CASCADE;
```

Inserted new constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD CONSTRAINT constraint UNIQUE (col1, col2);
```

Now get:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "constraint"
Key (col1, col2)=(123, "Monday") already exists
```

**Even though there are no such combination**

tableA also references(has foreign key column) to tableB which was not changed in any way.

Help appreciated.

Comment: what you mean tableA reference tableB? Inherit? did you try `select * from tableA`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal script which reproduces this? I imagine the script would create a table, add a constraint, then insert some data.

Comment: Often the act of attempting to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will point you to where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Running below query would confirm whether you have duplicate values or not.

```
SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*)
FROM tableA
GROUP BY col1, col2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If it returns rows then unique constraint failure is as expected.

Comment: It wouldn't be expected considering he truncated this and any referencing tables before adding constraint.